# change permission to user only

Tags: java, sftp

for a file, i need to change the user permission only,

```
Actual output is :::--x-wx--T
Expected output is::rw-------
```

Here is my sample code:

```
    String serverFileName = "FileInServer.txt";  
    sftp.upload("src/test/java/com/filecreation/testfile/"+fileName+".txt",serverFileName);    

    Session session = null;           

    JSch jsch=new JSch();  

    session=jsch.getSession("user", "host", port);

    session.setPassword(password);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 

    session.connect();

    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");

    if (!channel.isConnected()) 
    channel.connect();
    channel.chmod(600,"/home/user/FileInServer.txt");

    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is taking a value in based 10 but what you are passing is the permission in octal... To be fair, this should be mentioned in the documentation of [`ChannelSftp`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#chmod-int-java.lang.String-) because this is probably a common mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
channel.chmod(600,"/home/user/FileInServer.txt");
```

Permission values that you see used with chmod, like `644` or `755`, are in octal (base 8), not decimal. You're specifying decimal 600 here when you probably want octal 0600:

```
channel.chmod(0600,"/home/user/FileInServer.txt");
              ^-- Leading 0 indicating an octal number
```